# Objective-C macro for class message

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, c-preprocessor

I have a dictionary with color settings and tried this:

```
#define ColorWithString( x) [UIColor #x]

NSDictionary *settings = @{@"color" : @"whiteColor"};
UIColor *color = ColorWithString(settings[@"color"]);
```

I get an error `Expected identifier`.

I know there are some subtleties with string preprocessing. Maybe it is not even possible to send a dynamic message to a class. Any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at what your macro expands to:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor settings[@"color"]];
```

That’s obviously not legal Objective-C code. I think you could use `performSelector:` in combination with `NSSelectorFromString`:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:
    NSSelectorFromString(settings[@"color"])];
```

…but why not do simply this?

```
NSDictionary *colors = @{
    @"white" : [UIColor whiteColor],
    @"red"   : [UIColor redColor]
};
```

Comment: Very good suggestions. I have a configuration plist with many colors, many of which are defined as convenient categories on `UIColor`, such as `[UIColor goldColor]`, or `[UIColor colorWithHex:@"#00AA00"]` etc., so this is not quite working yet...

Comment: If I had the colors in an external configuration file, I guess I would opt to store the hex values and parse them, because a direct translation of configuration values to selector names sounds like trouble. If you don’t mind that, I think you can take the `NSSelectorFromString` way I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Thought about doing it exactly in this way (hex values). Thanks for your input.

Comment: Actually his macro expands to `UIColor *color = [UIColor "settings[@\"color\"]"];`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Macro to

```
#define ColorWithString( x) [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(x)]
```

And then you can use macro as

```
        NSDictionary *settings = @{@"color" : @"greenColor"};        
        UIColor *color = ColorWithString(settings[@"color"]);
```

To get a `CGColorRef` from a `UIColor`

```
CGColorRef colorRef = color.CGColor;
```

Comment: I keep getting an cryptic error, no stack trace, but in the thread `CGColorSpaceGetModel`...

Comment: the output is `UIColor`. I think what you need is a `CGColorRef`. Try assigning `color.CGColor` instead of `color` directly.

Comment: OK, that is a separate question... Sort of solved already. -- The macro works, but the performSelector was @zoul's idea ;-).